# wpf application cannot be restored from taskbar

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application that sometimes cannot be restored from the taskbar.  This typically happens when application has been running for a while but is not always the active window.  When this happens, application process has to be terminated from Task Manager.  What does this indicate and is there anything I can do about this?

TIA.

Comment: hold on a minute while I start up my crystal ball

Comment: @David, I so want to +10000 you :) Made my night =

Comment: What David's comment is trying to tell you is that there isn't enough information provided in your question for us to do anything more than speculate as to possible causes. This would be much easier for all of us if you could add more details and/or post some of your code. Try attaching a debugger to the currently running process and see what you find.

Comment: Please tell me what you need to know.  A code sample will not do it here.  This is one massive application and what I want to know is the types of things that would cause this, if the application had been running on a single screen setup.  Rick's answer below will help me determine if the application just went off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check is that the program is not simply off screen somewhere.

- Click the icon on the taskbar
- Press `Alt+Space`: displays the system menu
- Press `M`: shows the four-arrow cursor
- Press the right arrow key `->`: shows the normal cursor
- Move the mouse to move the application back onto the desktop

If this works, your next problem is to figure out how it got off screen.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Will try your suggestions when this happens again.  Unfortunately, it is an intermittent issue.